# i want to get comment once because it's repeated multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, socket.io

server-side:
here is the server-side where I get the comment

```
db.postSchema
              .findOne({ _id: comment.post })
              .populate("owner")
              .exec((err, users) => {
                for (let i = 0; i < array_of_connection.length; i++) {
                  for (let j = 0; j < users.owner.friends.length; j++) {
                    if (array_of_connection[i]._id == users.owner.friends[j]) {
                      array_of_connection[i].emit("new-comment", comment);
                    }
                  }
                }
              });
```

client-side:
and here where listen to the new comment: post.vue

```
created() {
   
   this.socket.on('new-comment',  data => {
     this.$store.commit('addComment', data)
   })
```

the problem here when i remove repeated comments: index.js

```
getPosts(state) {
      let unique = [...new Set(state.posts)];

      for (let i = 0; i < unique.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < unique[i].comments.length; j++) {
          for (let k = 0; k < unique[i].comments.length - 1; k++) {
            if (unique[i].comments[j]._id == unique[i].comments[k]._id) {
              unique[i].comments.splice(k, 1);
            }
          }
        }
      }
      return unique;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to splice the array you are iterating is not usually a good idea.
May I suggest adding the comments to an array, then returning it.

```
getPosts(state) {
 function removeDuplicateComments(post) {
  let ret = []
  post.comments.forEach(it=> {
    if (!ret.find(it2=>it2._id == it._id) {
      ret.push(it);
    }
  })
  post.comments=ret;
 }
 
 let unique = [...new Set(state.posts)];
 unique.forEach(removeDuplicateComments);

 return unique;
}
```

You can also use a map for faster id lookup, and return the values.  This may changed the insertion order however.

On thing to keep in mind is that this getter is mutating itself;  Not a great design.